# One solenoid inside the other

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

If I place one solenoid inside of the other, both of them in the same direction and same amount of loops, will the inductance be doubled or will it be zero?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you connect them. Inductance is ultimately an ability to create a magnetic field, which by Lenz's Law resists change, it has a sort of “inertia,” and this gives the current a corresponding sort of “inertia.”

If the currents around the solenoids both pass in the same direction, their magnetic fields will add up and they will have more inductance. If the currents around the solenoids are opposing each other, they will cancel out in the inside of the interior solenoid, and the magnetic field will be confined to the space between the two. This is not an automatic zero, but by making the inner solenoid larger you can get as close to zero as you want.

Comment: So should I connect the ends of the solenoids together? The one on the outside in one direction and the one on the inside, another direction? They will subtract then, right?

Comment: If they are both wound the same way (clockwise or counterclockwise) about the center then the nearest possible way to wire them in series will be subtractive, the current will go say clockwise up one solenoid and then counterclockwise down the other.

Answer (score 1):

If you place one solenoid inside of the other, with the same number of turns and the same area, and if the currents turn in the same direction, it is equivalent to doubling the number of turns. And since the inductance is proportional to the square of the number of turns, it is multiplied by 4.

If, under the same conditions, the currents turn in opposite directions, the field is zero and the inductance is zero.